# Distribution of independent random variables - textbook question

Tags: self-study, distributions, random-variable

The question is:

> Let $Y_1,....,Y_n$ be independent random variables each with the distribution $N\left ( \mu ,\sigma ^2 \right )$.
>
> Let:
>
> $\overline{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$
>
> $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i - \overline{Y} \right )^2$
>
> Show that: $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\mu  \right )^2 - n\left ( \overline{Y}-\mu  \right )^2 \right ]$

This is as far as I've being able to get:

$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i - \overline{Y} \right )^2$

$= \frac{1}{n-1}\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\overline{Y}  \right )\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left ( Y_j -\overline{Y} \right ) \right ]$

I intend the first double summation to be for when $i=j$ and the second for when $i\neq j$...

$= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\overline{Y} \right ) \left ( Y_j-\overline{Y} \right )+\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\overline{Y} \right ) \left ( Y_j-\overline{Y} \right )$

$= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\overline{Y} \right )^2 +\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left ( Y_i-\overline{Y} \right ) \left ( Y_j-\overline{Y} \right )$

Would anyone know how to finish the question off from here or any mistakes I've made thus far?

The question is exercise 1.4 from [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZzncBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&dq=dobson+generalised+linear+models+%2B+1.4+%2B+be+independent+random+variables+each+with+the+distribution&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB-pvO64PVAhVG7CYKHeHwAC4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=dobson%20generalised%20linear%20models%20%2B%201.4%20%2B%20be%20independent%20random%20variables%20each%20with%20the%20distribution&f=false).

Thank you.

Comment: This is an FAQ, mainly because this question is usually stated *exactly* the same way each time--but it's in mathematical notation, which is difficult to search!  I am confident there are at least 20 exact  duplicates here and would therefore be grateful to anyone who could locate one.

Comment: BTW, this question has nothing to do with independence, normality, or even random variables: it's a purely algebraic result.  Demonstrating it is merely an exercise in using summation notation. If that's not clear, write it out explicitly for the case $n=2$: the pattern should become apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As whuber points out, this is simply an exercise in algebra that has nothing to do with random variables or normality; all that is needed is the definition that $\bar{Y} \triangleq \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ which can be manipulated into 
$$0 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right)
- n\bar{Y} =  \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i -\bar{Y}) .$$
We have that
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu)^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y} + \bar{Y} - \mu)^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 + (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2 + 2(Y_i-\bar{Y})(\bar{Y}-\mu)\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2  + \sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2
+ \sum_{i=1}^n 2(Y_i-\bar{Y})(\bar{Y}-\mu)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 + n\cdot (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2
+ 2(\bar{Y}-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 + n\cdot (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2
+2 (\bar{Y}-\mu)\cancelto{0}{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 + n\cdot (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2\\
&\Downarrow\\
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 &= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu)^2 - n\cdot (\bar{Y}-\mu)^2\right].
\end{align}
Note that the proof works for all choices of number $\mu$; there is no
requirement that $\mu$ equal the expected value of anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, how did you know to start off with (Yi−μ)? Is there any other way to obtain μ from the original equation for S^2?